# Get array inside of array without knowing what is the first layer of array would be

Tags: php, arrays

```
echo $merchant_pic['shop']['campaign'];
```

I know that would give me the value of `campaign`. But first I have to know what is the first layer of the array - which is `shop`.

Problem is: the first layer could be anything.

Is there a way to get the value of second layer of array without knowing/defining what the first layer would be?

Comment: The question should be subjected to `str_replace('layer','key',$stackquestion);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the key of the target item inside `$merchant_pic` then you *have* to know its position relative to its siblings (is it the first item? the last? the third?).

If that is the only (or the first) item inside `$merchant_pic` then one way to get it easily is `reset($merchant_pic)`, so you would write

```
echo reset($merchant_pic)['campaign']; // requires PHP >= 5.4
```

Comment: Smart answer, but I'm still wondering whether it is sane to process anything that is essentially undefined with a computer.

Comment: @Tibo: It's not like that. It's quite common to get an array whose indexes mean nothing to you and you don't care about from some function (e.g. a list of user objects indexed by id). Imagine that you are only interested in the first user in the list. You don't know the key (id), but you also don't care.

Comment: I don't think this would work without hardcodding, if 2 or more `first layers` has key named `campaign`

Comment: @RoyalBg: That would be a different question entirely -- one easily solved with a plain `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the keys until find one

```
<?php
$merchant_pic['not_shop'] = array(
    'rrr' => 'aaa',
    2 => 'a',
    'foo' => 'bar'
);
$merchant_pic['shop'] = array(
    'bla' => 1,
    'asd' => 2,
    'campaign' => 'true (hit here)',
    'qwe' => 3
);

foreach ($merchant_pic as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($merchant_pic[$key]['campaign'])) {
        echo $merchant_pic[$key]['campaign'];
    }

}
```

Output: `true (hit here)`

In this case I don't know what $key is. It's `shop`, but it could be `not_shop`, aswell it could be in both, or in another key. It will iterate through all keys and everytime it return true to `isset()`, it will print it.